# Process all files in variable separatly in Makefile

Tags: c++, makefile

I have multiple source files in a directory, which some are responsible for a main executable, and some are responsible for a shared library, which then in turn is needed for the main executable. Thus I wrote the makefile in the following way:

```
CC=gcc
CXX=g++
CFLAGS=-I$(DIR) -fPIC -c -fopenmp
CXXLFLAGS=-I$(DIR) -fopenmp -O3 -g -march=native -std=gnu++17 -fPIC -c
CXXFLAGS=-I$(DIR) -fopenmp -O3 -g -march=native -std=gnu++17 -c
LDFLAGS=-lfftw3 -lgomp -lm -larmadillo -lpthread -lX11 -lboost_system -lboost_program_options -L/opt/intel/mkl/lib/intel64 -lmkl_rt
LDMAINFLAGS=-lfftw3 -lgomp -lm -larmadillo -lpthread -lX11 -lboost_system -lboost_program_options -L/opt/intel/mkl/lib/intel64 -lmkl_rt -lpulse_propagation
LIBSOURCES=source/image_processing.cpp source/pulse_propagation.cpp
LIBOBJECTS=source/image_processing.o source/pulse_propagation.o
MAINSOURCES=source/fftw.cpp source/fftw++.cc 
MAINOBJECTS=source/fftw.o source/fftw++.o 
EXECUTABLE=fftw
LIBRARY=libpulse_propagation.so

.PHONY: default all clean

default: all

all: $(LIBRARY) main

main: $(LIBRARY) $(MAINOBJECTS)
    $(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) $(MAINOBJECTS) -o $(EXECUTABLE)

$(LIBRARY): $(LIBOBJECTS)
    $(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) -shared $^ -o $@

$(LIBOBJECTS): $(LIBSOURCES)
    $(CXX) $(CXXLFLAGS) $^ -o $@

$(MAINOBJECTS): $(MAINSOURCES)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $^ -o $@

clean_compile:
    rm -f source/*.o

clean:
    rm -f source/*.o $(EXECUTABLE) $(LIBRARY)
```

with everything labeled with a `MAIN` belonging to the main executable and everything else to the library. I would like to loop over the files in `LIBSOURCES`/`MAINSOURCES` and compile each of them. I would prefer if I do not have to use the `.cpp.o:`-macro, after there are different flags depending if it is a library file or a main file. I tried using `$<`, which executed the compilation twice (ok), but always used the first value from the variable list. When using `$^` instead, both files are used at once, also resulting in an error. How could I else do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `source/fftw++.cc` instead of `source/fftw++.cpp` makes everything uselessly complex. If you can rename it, then the following should do what you want:

```
$(LIBOBJECTS): CXXFLAGS := $(CXXLFLAGS)

$(LIBOBJECTS) $(MAINOBJECTS): %.o: %.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

The first line defines the value of variable `CXXFLAGS` for the `$(LIBOBJECTS)` targets. The following rule is a [static pattern rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Static-Pattern) that translates into as many rules with one target and one prerequisite only. It is completely different from your rules that declares **all** source files of one kind as prerequisites of **all** corresponding object files. Not what you want normally.

If you cannot rename `source/fftw++.cc` you can split your sources and objects lists:

```
MAINCPPSOURCES=source/fftw.cpp
MAINCCSOURCES=source/fftw++.cc 
MAINCPPOBJECTS=source/fftw.o
MAINCCOBJECTS=source/fftw++.o 

$(LIBOBJECTS): CXXFLAGS := $(CXXLFLAGS)

$(LIBOBJECTS) $(MAINCPPOBJECTS): %.o: %.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $< -o $@

$(MAINCCOBJECTS): %.o: %.cc
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

Finally, it would probably  be better (easier to maintain) if you were computing what can be, instead of hard-wiring it in your Makefile:

```
MAINCPPOBJECTS = $(patsubst %.cpp,%.o,$(MAINCPPSOURCES))
MAINCCOBJECTS = $(patsubst %.cc,%.o,$(MAINCCSOURCES))
...
```

Comment: I can rename it, but would prefer not to, due to getting it from an external source (fftw).

Comment: And what about a symbolic link named `source/fftw++.cpp` and pointing to `source/fftw++.cc`?